# Which scientific and ethical principles could rule an animal society accepting both collaboration (symbiosis) and exploitation (parasitism)?

Tags: animal-locomotion

**BACKGROUND:** On many pre-industrial human societies, agriculture, transportation and industry were based on nonhuman animal (referred as "nonhuman" thereafter) exploitation, and more than a few on human exploitation, through the trade of human slaves. Fortunately, such human and non human animal (referred as ``animal'' thereafter) exploitation was greatly reduced as a consequence of the adoption of engines fueled by fossil sources of energy, more transportable and practical than animal exploitation.

**PROBLEM:** As human societies stop using such fossil sources of energy, and non-animal renewable sources of energy (such as solar, wind and geothermic) seem unable to completely replace such sources of energy, there is the distinct possibility that some or all will return to such animal exploitation practices, and ignore centuries of cultural, scientific and ethical advancement, "returning to the past" in many aspects.

**QUESTION:** Which scientific knowledge would be key to design new agricultural, transportation and/or industrial processes using animal power, more aligned with the concept of collaboration (between humans, and between humans and nonhumans) than with that of exploitation?

**EXISTING EXAMPLES:**

- Permaculture designs can be used to imagine and create auto sustainable "edible forests" which provide food for a stable population of human and nonhuman animals;
- Some wild birds taught themselves to collect garbage in parks in exchange of seeds;
- Some elephants are trained to transport and manipulate heavy charges like tree trunks;
- Some ducks were trained to eat snails on cultures;
- Some insects were trained to selectively eat some specific parasites;

**HYPOTHETICAL EXAMPLES:**

- Some horses could be trained to return to their "taxi central" without needing human supervision;
- Some beavers could be trained to build wood barriers on rivers in a way helping the generation of hydro-electricity.

(I am also curious about the ethical aspect of such collaborative/symbiotic relations.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails "the book test": If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: Include more concrete details about your world. What kind of creatures live in your world? And what in the world does point 2 mean?

Comment: @Daron I am thinking about a parallel world to our own which would have evolved from the same creatures which lived on earth in the 15th century in a world where engines were either not invented, or did not take such a prominent position in society, possibly due to a refusal to use fossil energies or to consume forms of energies faster than they are replenished.

Comment: @Jeremy Are they just normal animals or are they smarter?

Comment: @Daron Nonhuman animals beat human ones on many measures of cognitive functions (from memory to sense of orientation), same as in our world :)

Comment: It's a fair question.  I doubt the OP and I have much agreement regarding animal politics, but the topic is interesting and the relevant ideas can be explored in broad outline.  Just because you *can* write a book doesn't mean you *have* to!

Comment: LOL +1 for beavers helping with hydro-electricity

Answer (score 1):

## Animal language

This is a broad topic, and often there is not a very large gap between listening for the submissive croak a crow makes on being challenged by a piece of bread out the window, versus reading what passes for an [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/avian-einsteins/201207/the-alluring-language-crows-and-ravens).  But let's suppose that "advanced natural language AI" can now talk to both you and to every type of animal in your local biome.  Well, then it should be more conceivable to make some kind of arrangement.

There are, of course, wild cards in this:  we don't know how much the animals can comprehend the idea of making a deal, it's not clear how smart they could possibly be, and their abilities are limited.  We don't know if the magic AI can use design flaws in their communications methods *(or ours for that matter)* to basically mind control them into doing things in a way you call parasitic.  *(Have you been to an election lately?)*  It's even conceivable that learning how to talk to bears means that bears start threatening humans to leave out their trash, *or else!*  In any case, adding highly effective communication is bound to make for a more interesting human-animal environment for any story.  It's certainly not implausible - the only question is how far out on the limb you can go before the audience stops following.

Comment: Very good point, I had not thought about that. A "universal translator" has the potential to radically change the scene (both in terms of non human exploitation and collaboration, which both exist in nature as parasitic and symbiotic relations) and, at the same time, enough caveats to require deep reflection and generate deep discussions. Thanks a lot for the idea!!!  [As a side note, many non human animals understand the concept of deal, from apes to parrots and ravens.]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by exploitation and collaboration.  A milk cow born and raised in captivity is dependent upon her owners to provide food protection and medicine. Dose this count as collaboration? You could say that the milk cow is producing milk in exchange for food shelter and medicine.

Also, I am not sure whether or not you mean to maintain our current morality or invent a new one . Remember most people consider it ethical to kill and eat animals. If so, they all you need is a set of laws requiring a certain level of treatment for domestic animals; no need for any new scientific discoveries.

If the later, you will need some sort of artificial meat.

Comment: By exploitation and collaboration, I mean parasitic and symbiotic relations (which both exist outside of human societies, without any moral judgement: they just are).  Human morality is constantly evolving with technology (slave traffic used not to be an issue, and some say that it ended more because engines running on fossil oil are cheaper than slaves than because of moral issues), and I not only would expect it to continue changing, but would like to explore the ways in which it could change, that's one of the reason to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the second part of your argument, especially given the first part: 
Two species can collaborate (E.g. North American native human tribes fostering some nonhuman animal species, Massai drinking the blood of their cows without killing them) even though individuals from one could kill or maim individuals from the other.
[And two individuals from distinct species can collaborate even though the first one's species generally exploints the second one's species?]

Comment: @Jeremy yes exactly what im saying depending on your meaning  we already have parasitic and symbiotic relations with animals.

Comment: @Jeremy i Just want you to clear on what moral expectations you are regarding human and  animal relations. Basicly I need to know when you say exploitative practices you wiether or not you mean to include killing and eating animals.